# Create instance variable to determine if class was initilized from __main__

Tags: python

As an exercise, I am building a debugging module that can determine if a a portion of code was either imported or defined the `__main__` scope, and then change the formatting of print statements accordingly. Suppose I have my module `debug.py`:

```py
class printer:
    def __init__(self):
       self.called_from_main = foo() 

    def print(self, arg):
        if self.called_from_main: print(arg)
        else: print(arg.upper())
```

I want to be able write a script (let's call it `test.py`),

```py
from debug import printer

p=printer()
p.print('Hello World')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("done")
```

with the following behavior:

1. When the file is run in __main__, 'Hello World' and 'done' are printed.
2. When the file is imported, 'HELLO WORLD' is printed.

It feels as though there must be a clean, pythonic way to define `foo()` without having to add any additional parameters to `__init__()` or play with global variables.

All input is tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Just tested the solution there using `inspect.currentframe()` and it worked beautifully! Should get you what you want. Just dropped it into your init method, then inside the `if` block in that answer I simply set your instance variable `called_from_main` to `frame.f_globals["__name__"] == "__main__"` It would be best, as that answer does, to register this in `__new__` and not `__init__`.

Comment: Just for some description of what is happening here---the class `printer` needs access to whatever is in scope at the time when you instantiate the object. But the *class* itself can't imagine where it will be, so you have to inspect the stack when the instance is created to figure out the context where it was created. To do this, you just pop off the stack frame and look at the `__file__` global to see if the file where it was instantiated is main or not.

Comment: Thank you! I would have never thought of that on my own.

Comment: Update @alkasm: I implemented the suggested solution. Inside the staticmethod _initilization_location() within the linked solution, we also need to change the line:   `if (frame.f_code.co_name == '<module>'):` to   `if (frame.f_code.co_name == '<module> and frame.f_globals['__name__'] != "debug"):` (once again, the class was defined in debug.py). Otherwise we will always stop at the 'debug' scope whenever the class is imported to test.py, as it was above.

Comment: Cool! It might be nice to edit your post with the solution that worked for you. The question is a dupe, but the application may be what users are looking for.

Comment: I just had a similar problem used this following gist to check if the caller was the original main : https://gist.github.com/benoit-dubreuil/fd3769be002280f3a22315d58d9976a4